# git submodule add fatal: Not a Git Repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am fairly new to Git and trying my best to find some documentation on this problem to no avail.

Here's my command:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/joliver/EventStore.git externalsource/JOliverEventStore/
```

> fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/externalsource/JOliverEventStore
>       Unable to checkout submodule 'externalsource/JOliverEventStore'

I am in my root of my repo and there is currently no directory for `/externalsource/JO
liverEventStore/`. The error is talking about a directory that I have no knowledge of.

If I add the submodule to the root dir like this:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/joliver/EventStore.git JOliverEventStore
```

I have no problem and it creates the folder in the root directory.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try createing the `externalsource` directory and then cd'ing to it and adding the submodule?

Comment: i did and when adding a submodule you have to do so from the root directory was the error back

Comment: You have a slash at the end of `JOliverEventStore` in the original command. Perhaps git is too stupid to think that you want to checkout to `JOliverEventStore` below the directory `JOliverEventStore` (which does not exists)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can depends on the version of Git you are using: this [recent thread (February 2012)](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/BUG-Fail-to-add-a-module-in-a-subdirectory-if-module-is-already-cloned-td7221426.html) mentions a bug:

> Since recently a submodule with name `<name>` has its git directory in the `.git/modules/<name>` directory of the superproject while the work tree contains a `gitfile` pointing there.
>
> When the same submodule is added on a branch where it wasn't present so far (it is not found in the .gitmodules file), the name is not initialized from the path as it should.
>   This leads to a wrong path entered in the `gitfile` when the `.git/modules/<name>` directory is found, as this happily uses the - now empty - name.
>   It then always points only a single directory up, even if we have a path deeper in the directory hierarchy.

But more generally, uses the `<path>` argument of [`git submodule`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-submodule):

> `<path>` is the relative location for the cloned submodule to exist in the superproject.
>
> - If `<path>` does not exist, then the submodule is created by cloning from the named URL.
> - If `<path>` does exist and is already a valid git repository, then this is added to the changeset without cloning.
>     This second form is provided to ease creating a new submodule from scratch, and presumes the user will later push the submodule to the given URL.

---

[eoinoc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248220/eoinoc) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048783/git-submodule-add-fatal-not-a-git-repository/10053363?noredirect=1#comment23748683_10053363) another cause, which is detailed in the question "[`git status` returns `fatal: Not a git repository but .git exists and HEAD has proper permissions`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144149/6309)".

> My repo's location had changed, and I needed to update git's configuration files.

Comment: Thanks vonc.  I saw that article too.  An update is prolly in order. I didn't see if it was resolved in last release though.  It seems like such a common task I was surprised to see the issue

Comment: Upgrading from git 1.6.x (included with Mountain Lion) to 1.8.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: The bug was not the cause of me seeing the same error message. My repo's location had changed, and I needed to update git's configuration files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144149/git-status-returns-fatal-not-a-git-repository-but-git-exists-and-head-has-prop

Comment: @eoinoc good to know. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

This will seem silly, but since I just wasted 30 minutes on that stupid mistake....

You parent repository must have already been created as git repository. I had just created the parent, then I created the submodule and & tried to `git submodule add` into the parent. However, the parent hadn't been initialized as a git repo.

This resulted in the same error as the one you mentioned ("not a git repository"). However it was the parent which wasn't a git repository.... silly.

Answer (score 5):

i wasted several minutes just for a simple problem

first `git init`

and then install theme `git submodule add https://github.com/joliver/EventStore.git JOliverEventStore`