# "Not a git repository: " Error when trying to add RestKit to my repository

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I am trying to start using git with my project.

I had (in the past) cloned RestKit to my project for use (I think that as a submodule but I am not sure. Now everything is working great and 99% of my files are tracked and pushed to Github.

When I try to add RestKit/ to my repository I get this error:

> shanis-imac:shannoga-English-Club shannoga$ git add RestKit/
>   fatal: Not a git repository: /Users/shannoga/github/shannoga-English-Club/.git/modules/RestKit

Now I can guess that I am not spoused to push rest kit but somehow to relate it to my repository?

1. Am I right?
2. What does the error mean
3. What is the way to do that?

Thanks, Shani

Comment: What version of git are you using? (because there was a bug in previous versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048783/git-submodule-add-fatal-not-a-git-repository). Or it could just be a naming conflict (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144149/git-status-returns-fatal-not-a-git-repository-but-git-exists-and-head-has-prop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [ResKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) is already declared as a submodule in your [current GitHub project](https://github.com/shannoga/Beffective), you shouldn't have to clone it / add it directly (not `git add` should be involved).

Following [Git Tools - Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), you should:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

That will fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject.

A `git clone --recursive` of your main project would have included this step for you: see "[How do I get `git clone --recursive` to recreate submodules' remotes and branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666085/how-do-i-get-git-clone-recursive-to-recreate-submodules-remotes-and-branche/11451714#11451714)", and don't forget, as explained in that last SO question, that the submodules are checked out in a [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714).

Comment: @shannoga just added the `git clone --recursive` trick, for the next time you will have to clone your main project.

Comment: Thanks again I will try that next time