# Can't add files to git repository

Tags: git

I'm adding a new project to a new Git repository.

I did `git init`, and when I do `git add .` it says :

> `fatal: Not a git repository: MyProject-iOS/Frameworks/AFNetworking.git/../../../.git/modules/MyProject-iOS/Frameworks/AFNetworking.git`

Framework structure is very strange in the project, I inherited it from someone else.

What to do and how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a .git folder in your repo right now?

Comment: @Vwin yes, I guess it appeared after init

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that:

- you are creating a git repo within an existing git repo (which isn't the right way to "add a new project"),
- that existing repo has a submodule with path that has changed (the folder for that submodule has been renamed): see "[git status returns fatal: Not a git repository but .git exists and HEAD has proper permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144149/6309)".
  That is true especially for [older versions of Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053363/6309) (before 1.8/1.9).

The easiest way out of this is:

- clone again the main repo (followed by a `cd mainrepo; git submodule update --init --recursive`)
- inside, to "add new projects", use `git submodule add /url/repo/new/project`, instead of `git init/git add`, if you want to consider those projects as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)** of the main parent repo.

Comment: I'm guessing this was third-party source they published by simply deleting a clone's `.git` directory and OP's making a repo for his own use. Publishers forget to strip the submodule's gitfile is all that has to happen to get this symptom then.